# How to use I2C library

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

My A4 and A5 pins are already hooked up to a LCD and I want to connect a MPU6050 as well. In a separate thread, someone told me to use SoftI2CMaster library to use other pins as SDA ans SCL. But I don't quite know how to do that. I want to use A2 and A3 for I2C, and a code snippet would be very helpful.

Comment: Are there no examples in the SoftI2CMaster library?

Comment: I tried following them, but got a lot of errors, a lot of them

Comment: in previous question it was ultrasonic sensor on A4 and A5. now it is LCD. has the LCD I2C interface? I2C is a bus. you can wire more I2C devices to the I2C pins

Comment: Yeah the LCD's got I2C. Tried wiring them like that, didn't work.

Comment: Oh and yeah, my bad. Wrote ultrasonic sensor by mistake : /

Comment: `got a lot of errors, a lot of them` ... are we supposed to guess what they were?

Comment: You really should use the hardware I2C bus on A4 and A5 for both devices. Describe exactly, how it didn't work when you tried. Provide a schematic or wiring diagram and show us your code. Then we will look, if we can spot the problem.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Ya, I will jump on the bandwagon and say again that I2C is a bus, it is designed to handle multiple devices.  Work on getting it to work correctly rather then hoping that bitbanging it with software is going to work.

Comment: If you are not using PULL UP in your SCL SDA lines please use them as I2C lines are open drain by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use both devices on I2C, with different addresses.  Hook it up like this

[image]

And call each transmission with a different address

```
void setup() {   
  Wire.begin();                           //begin the wire comunication  
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
```

Image and snippet from [electronoob's very complete tutorial](http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut76.php)